# R library for amino acid descriptors

Tags: python, r

I am working with amino acid sequences in a protein. 
Is there any library in R or a module in Python that can be used to extract features for a machine learning model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, there's a protr and RCPI library in R that can be used for this purpose.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/protr/vignettes/protr.html

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rcpi.html

Also in python there's an iFeature module that you can use to extract the features.